# Reducing the Number of Passes

Tags: algorithm, optimization, cluster-analysis, combinatorics, approximation

Consider the following clustering algorithm in a semi-streaming setting.

Suppose edges of a graph are coming in a stream and the clustering is done in the following way. Here N(u) denotes the neighborhood of vertex u and p is a random permutation of the vertices so that p(u) is the rank of the vertex in that permutation.

1. All vertices are unmarked initially.
2. Call any unmarked vertex v a center if p(v) < p(u) for all the vertices u in N(v). After this, mark v and all vertices in N(v).
3. The centers will form centers of clusters. For the vertices that are not called "center", say u, we look at N(u). If there is no such "center" vertex in the neighborhood, u forms a singleton cluster. Else u joins the cluster of that central vertex.

Now I think the above algorithm can be implemented in some constant number of passes over the stream, I guess that constant number is 3.

But my question is can we do the same thing in 1 pass? Can we store information cleverly in some way so that we can do the above or something close to the above in 1 pass? The assumption here should be that we have O(n) storage space, so we cant store all edges. Also, I will appreciate an algorithm in linear time. O(n^2) time algorithm might be able to do it in one pass, not sure.

Comment: You have 2 assumptions: that you can't store all edges (as it's semi-streaming) and therefore probably can't store `p` either; and that which vertices are selected as a "center" is irrelevant and can be done randomly (or not). These assumptions imply that the solution to the real/original problem should never have involved any useless "random permutation" distraction. This forces me to ask, what is the real/original problem (and for fun, why did anyone think "random permutations" were a useful part of the solution)?

Comment: Did you intend the 3-step algorithm you gave to be a description of an unrestricted algorithm (i.e., an algorithm that is able to operate on the complete state), which you are hoping to mimic with a semi-streaming algorithm? Because the output of the algorithm you gave depends on the order that *vertices* are processed -- which you don't specify. Separately: 'If there is no such "center" vertex in the neighborhood' -- this can't happen. Every vertex will eventually be marked, and at the time a vertex v is marked, it is either a center itself, or some neighbour of it is.

Comment: @j_random_hacker About the separate point that you make saying: 'If there is no such "center" vertex in the neighborhood' -- this can't happen,
the center/pivot must have a smaller rank than the neighbors that are currently unmarked. Also for a non-central vertex, u, we look at N(u). There will be a vertex of minimum rank. But this does not mean it will be a pivot/center by definition. There is a picture on pg 4 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/2205.03710.pdf
The paper is "Almost 3-Approximate Correlation Clustering
in Constant Rounds"

Comment: @Brendan The 3-step algorithm is also a semi-streaming algorithm but it is allowed multiple passes on the stream to achieve the result. The algorithm does depend on the order of the vertices and during analysis, the authors usually take expectation over all such orderings. As j_random_hacker has correctly predicted, I want to do the same thing but let's say I am allowed only one pass over the stream. We use the Min-wise independence of S_n to take expectation over all orderings. The algorithm is called "r-Pivot" see pg 4 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/2205.03710.pdf

Comment: It seems my assumption that your 3-step algorithm was designed to operate on the full state was wrong, and instead it somehow operates on the edges as they stream in -- correct? But if so, what does "N(v)" mean? We never know the complete set of neighbours of any vertex v at any point during the running of a semi-streaming algorithm (if we were allowed to store this information as we went, we would know it at the very end -- but we aren't allowed to, since storing that information would require O(|E|) space).